# Last file line reading gives different results

Tags: c++, file-handling, strlen, file-read

I am trying to read strings from a file with contents like:

```
r FFFF

r FF

r FFFF
```

Here is my code:

```
int main ()
{   int a; ifstream ifile; 
   ifile.open("hi.txt"); 
  while (!ifile.eof()) 
   { 
      ifile.getline(data, 100); // read a line from file
      a = strlen(data);
      cout<<'length"<<a;
    }
}
```

I am getting unexpected outputs: `length7length5length6`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you want to happen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 0):

The '\n' (new line character) is in `data`. On windows you might also have a '\n\r' instead (or '\r\n' I don't remember)

on the last line you might not have it in your text file